# Showing that two unitary matrices are equal up to a global phase

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, mathematics, unitarity, linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be two $d × d$ unitary matrices, representing two reversible quantum processes
on a $d$-dimensional quantum system. We say that the two processes “act in the same way”
on the state $|ψ\rangle$ if the vectors $U|\psi\rangle$ and $V|\psi\rangle$ are equal up to a global phase.

Show that, if the two processes represented by $U$ and $V$ act in the same way on every input state in the set $S = \{|n\rangle,n=0,\ldots,d-1\} \cup \{{|e_0\rangle}\}$ with $|e_0\rangle :=\ \sum_{n = 0} ^{d-1}\ \frac{|n\rangle}{ \sqrt d}$,  then the unitary matrices $U$ and $V$ are equal up to a global phase.

For every $|n\rangle $ we have $U|n\rangle = Ve^{i\theta_n}|n\rangle$, which can then be substituted into the summation, but that doesn't help us arrive at $U = e^{i\theta}V$.

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit explaining my attempt at the problem

Comment: Since you require that $U$ and $V$ act the same way on $\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}\frac{|n\rangle}{\sqrt{d}}$, so the global phase $\theta_n$ should be the same, i.e., $\theta_1=\theta_2=...=\theta_{d-1}=\theta$ in your notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unitary operators $U$ and $V$ act in the same way on $|n\rangle$ for $n=0,\dots,d-1$, so there exist $\theta_n\in[0,2\pi)$ such that

$$
U|n\rangle=e^{i\theta_n}V|n\rangle.\tag1
$$

Also, $U$ and $V$ act in the same way on $|e_0\rangle$, so there exists $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
U|e_0\rangle&=e^{i\theta}V|e_0\rangle\\
\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}U|n\rangle&=e^{i\theta}\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}V|n\rangle.\tag2
\end{align}
$$

Substituting from $(1)$ into $(2)$, we get

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}e^{i\theta_n}V|n\rangle=e^{i\theta}\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}V|n\rangle\tag3
$$

and setting $|n'\rangle:=V|n\rangle$, we can rewrite $(3)$ as

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}\left(e^{i\theta_n}-e^{i\theta}\right)|n'\rangle=0.\tag4
$$

Now, $V$ is unitary and $|n\rangle$ are orthonormal, so $|n'\rangle$ are orthonormal. In particular, $|n'\rangle$ are linearly independent. Therefore, $(4)$ implies that $\theta_n=\theta$ for every $n=0,\dots,d-1$. But then $(1)$ implies that $U=e^{i\theta}V$.